# how to read and write to connected PCI devices in assembly languages?

Tags: linux, assembly, driver, pci, nic

I was learning about hardware and driver programming. I tried to analyze the code that was programmed for menuetOS on PCI, Ethernet, and Ethernet Cards. I could understand the concepts and what each part does.
I start to program PCI and Ethernet for my own Laptop but I couldn't get Vendor and Device ID
in Kali Linux. actually, I got either a syntax error or segmentation fault. I was trying to use code that I use to get Vendor and Device ID in MS-DOS.The [CODE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgzT1JfBUr0&list=PLBTQvUDSl81dTG_5Uk2mycxZihfeAYTRm&index=8):

```
eax: 80000000
ecx: 00000020

0100 : mov dx,0cf8
0103 : out dx,eax
0105 : mov dx,0cfc
0108 : mov ebp, eax
010B : in eax,dx
010D : cmp eax,FFFFFFFF
0113 : je 0130
0115 : mov ds:[ebx],eax
011A : add ebx,0004
011E : mov [ebx],ebp
0123 : add ebx,0004
0127 : mov eax,ebp
012A : add eax,00000800
0130 : loop 0100
```

and it writes:

```
ds: 0000 12378086 80000000
ds: 0008 80008086 80000800
ds: 0010 BEEF80EE 00001000
            .
            .
            .
```

**Q1:** How can I get these values in NASM then print them? (actually, I don't know the start address for write to or read from different devices and don't know how to find them in memory)

**Q2:** How The Operating Systems (Like Windows or Linux) Can Connect to the internet before we install the NIC's Driver?

Thank YOU

Comment: Your code will not run on Linux due to memory protection.  You can try to make it work by giving yourself appropriate permissions using `iopl`, but it may then crash your entire system if you do it wrong.  As for Q2, that's a separate question and you should ask only one question per question.  The answer however is “it cannot.”

Comment: 2. By already containing drivers for most NICs, or by doing networking over a serial port or whatever.  Linux distros build their kernels with drivers for every NIC supported by Linux enabled as a module.

Comment: q1: bios enumerates the pci devices and assigns addresses, in linux you can use lspci to find them, but you still need the docs for the device/chip.  q2:  you dont, you use another os on the same machine or some other machine to get files and move them.   or wifi if you dont consider that a NIC.